# How do I ensure that my React.js application updates user input based on a selection option?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I am trying to build an application using React.js that accepts data from a user through a series of inputs and selection options and then returns to the user the result of a calculation using the data entered. The problem I am facing is that I want to be able to change the data a user entered into an input based on what selection option they selected, however, each time I go to run the calculation it uses the old value instead of the new value I tried to create based on the selection option.

Here is an example of the code I've been attempting to try. I am still very new to React but am trying to better my understanding of hook functionality.

```
function TestApp() {

    const [measurement, setMeasurement] = useState(0);
    const [selectMeasurement, setSelectMeasurement] = useState('');

    const handleMeasurementInput = ({target}) => {
        const newNumber = target.value;

        if (!Number.isNaN(Number(newNumber))) {
            setMeasurement(target.value);
        };
    };

    const handleMeasurementSelect = ({target}) => {
        const newSelection = target.value;
        setSelectMeasurement(newSelection);
    };

    const onClickFunc = () => {
    
        if (selectMeasurement !== 'option1') {
            return measurement;
        } else {
            return setMeasurement(prev => prev / 12);
        };

        console.log(measurement);
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <label>Measurement</label>
            <input
                type='number'
                id='measurement'
                name='measurement'
                value={measurement}
                onChange={handleMeasurementInput}
            />
            <select id='select1' onChange={handleMeasurementSelect}>
                <option value=''>select</option>
                <option value='option1'>Option 1</option>
                <option value=''option2'>Option 2</option>
            </select>
            <input
                type='button'
                value='Calculate'
                id='btn'
                onClick={onClickFunc}
            />
        </form>
    );

}
```

When I enter a number like **145** into the **Measurement** input and then click the **Calculate** button the number inside of the input changes to **12.0833** however when I view the Console it still says **145** and this is affecting my final output when I incorporate more values into the calculation.

Comment: Your console.log is outside of the function scope - the `return` statement is reached regardless of the values so it never prints anything to the console. Plus, you have a bad select value for option 2 (too many '). But fixing these 2 things and dropping this into a code-sandbox - works fine for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-shockley-v7lfi0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Appreciated! It is working as expected now.